Only allowing certain countries acess website cpanel htaccess
I've tried both codes and they seem to only block all and not do what they are suppose to be.
I use my website and a Germany proxy. I should be able to access it on my ip but give error when using proxy.
This code will redirect all traffic to example.com even when using USA server as well as proxy. But this answer here says "it should. You could simply use negation ! to redirect anything but China CN and Russia RU.", but when I replace them with US | CA still redirect all not just others except us and ca
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} !^(US|CA)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/us/$1 [L]

and this code blocks all even us and ca tho it should not unless im doing somin wrong?
<IfModule mod_geoip.c>
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE US PermitCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE CA PermitCountry
Deny from All
Allow from env=PermitCountry
</IfModule>


Can you clarify where the proxy comes into this (Its unclear if you are using a proxy to access cpanel or if your cpanel install is behind a proxy).     Also, why would you expect this to work if you are behind a german proxy - the site will see you coming from a german IP, so presumably you want to add a "SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE DE PermitCountry" line to allow requests from Germany?

Or alterantatively "RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} !^(US|CA|DE)$ in the first example.
